# Using own image in sklearn digits example

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I've been toying around with sklearn and python and try to understand how machine learning works. I got the basic examples right but there's one thing I'm struggling with.

For example let's say I'm using the digits dataset, once I got my classifier ready and tested. How would I go about using an image of my own handwriting in that example?

I managed to load the image and read it's pixels with matplotlib but I get an array with (8,8,3) out of it and a sample from the digits dataset has a shape of (8,8).

This is the code I'm using to get the classifier trained

```
digits = load_digits()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(digits.data, digits.target, test_size=0.20)

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)

clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

img = mpimg.imread('handwritten.jpg')
```

Here's a print of what I get from `print(img)`

```
[[[245 251 255]
  [ 51  55  82]
  [ 41  56  87]
  [ 18  58 109]
  [ 11  65 125]
  [ 20  64 101]
  [242 255 255]
  [255 255 239]]

 [[249 253 255]
  [249 254 255]
  [239 255 255]
  [221 255 255]
  [209 255 255]
  [ 16  60 105]
  [242 255 255]
  [255 253 242]]

 [[250 254 255]
  [250 255 255]
  [241 255 255]
  [218 255 255]
  [ 10  69 137]
  [ 10  57 111]
  [241 255 255]
  [255 253 250]]

 [[252 255 253]
  [251 255 252]
  [ 44  61  77]
  [ 16  60 109]
  [  3  63 136]
  [ 13  61 123]
  [240 255 255]
  [255 253 255]]

 [[251 255 249]
  [252 255 250]
  [239 255 255]
  [ 19  63 112]
  [  3  63 136]
  [ 16  64 128]
  [240 255 255]
  [255 252 255]]

 [[249 255 253]
  [249 255 253]
  [240 255 255]
  [218 255 255]
  [  3  59 133]
  [ 17  62 121]
  [242 255 255]
  [255 252 255]]

 [[245 255 255]
  [245 255 255]
  [236 254 255]
  [220 255 255]
  [ 14  67 135]
  [ 19  59 111]
  [245 255 255]
  [255 253 250]]

 [[241 255 255]
  [ 46  58  74]
  [ 38  58  83]
  [ 21  61 110]
  [  9  60 123]
  [224 255 255]
  [246 255 255]
  [255 254 243]]]
(64,)
[[[245 251 255]
  [ 51  55  82]
  [ 41  56  87]
  [ 18  58 109]
  [ 11  65 125]
  [ 20  64 101]
  [242 255 255]
  [255 255 239]]

 [[249 253 255]
  [249 254 255]
  [239 255 255]
  [221 255 255]
  [209 255 255]
  [ 16  60 105]
  [242 255 255]
  [255 253 242]]

 [[250 254 255]
  [250 255 255]
  [241 255 255]
  [218 255 255]
  [ 10  69 137]
  [ 10  57 111]
  [241 255 255]
  [255 253 250]]

 [[252 255 253]
  [251 255 252]
  [ 44  61  77]
  [ 16  60 109]
  [  3  63 136]
  [ 13  61 123]
  [240 255 255]
  [255 253 255]]

 [[251 255 249]
  [252 255 250]
  [239 255 255]
  [ 19  63 112]
  [  3  63 136]
  [ 16  64 128]
  [240 255 255]
  [255 252 255]]

 [[249 255 253]
  [249 255 253]
  [240 255 255]
  [218 255 255]
  [  3  59 133]
  [ 17  62 121]
  [242 255 255]
  [255 252 255]]

 [[245 255 255]
  [245 255 255]
  [236 254 255]
  [220 255 255]
  [ 14  67 135]
  [ 19  59 111]
  [245 255 255]
  [255 253 250]]

 [[241 255 255]
  [ 46  58  74]
  [ 38  58  83]
  [ 21  61 110]
  [  9  60 123]
  [224 255 255]
  [246 255 255]
  [255 254 243]]]
```

and here's one from a sample digit

```
[  0.   0.   5.  13.   9.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.  13.  15.  10.  15.   5.
   0.   0.   3.  15.   2.   0.  11.   8.   0.   0.   4.  12.   0.   0.   8.
   8.   0.   0.   5.   8.   0.   0.   9.   8.   0.   0.   4.  11.   0.   1.
  12.   7.   0.   0.   2.  14.   5.  10.  12.   0.   0.   0.   0.   6.  13.
  10.   0.   0.   0.]
```

As you can see not only the shape is different but also the values of the features, the sample from the dataset contains only integers from 0 to 16 and mine has RGB values.

So how do I "normalize" my data to be able to use my classifier on it?

Comment: Do a grayscale-conversion and discretize to obtain the desired resolution. Original MNIST though started with binary images and obtained the non-binary resolution due to anti-aliasing. The former is basic image processing. More important: did you crop and normalize the sizes (while keeping the aspect ratio)? That's very very important, especially for SVM-based approaches. See [here](http://mldata.org/repository/data/viewslug/mnist-original/) for a description of the MNIST data. There is a pessimistic rule i use: *face-recognition is all about the data-sets*.This partially could apply here too.

Comment: I actually just managed to get a somewhat good output by doing grayscale + invert (both with PIL). I started testing with 8x8 digits drawn by myself and now I was testing other sizes, so I did a resize of the original image to make it fit in a 8x8 matrix. It confuses some numbers due to the resize though.

Comment: Yes, it sounds you are changing the ratios. 8x8 is also not much information. Inversion or not should not change anything! And always standardize your input!

Comment: Am i? my "big" images are 64x64.. resizing to 8x8 doesn't sound like a change ratio

Comment: But how did you crop? Or did you write on some pre-marked paper?

Comment: Oh my bad, maybe I wasn't clear enough. Those images are digital images. I made them with Pixelmator (Paint for what it's worth). I have a long way to go before I start cropping actual paper-handwritten digits and stuff haha

Comment: Okay. Well... my first step would be not going for 8x8, but something bigger. And if you are curious: there are some very simple (actually at least 4-5) keras-based examples using Neural-networks on MNIST (most interesting: basic MLP and basic CNN). The good thing is, that it sounds like you can generate an infinite amount of samples (although there should be some differences between them to make it worth, e.g. some well-defined noise).

Answer (score 3):

Continuously with the code from standard [Recognizing hand-written digits](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html), I had ugly working code like below. (hope get improved by others)

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

img = mpimg.imread('/code/4.png')
gray = rgb2gray(img)
a=(16-gray*16).astype(int) # really weird here, but try to convert to 0..16
plt.imshow(a, cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray_r'))
plt.show()
print("source data in 8x8:\n",a)

predicted = classifier.predict(a.flatten().reshape(1, -1))
print(predicted)
```

See result

[image]

The `4.png` is 
[image]

Steps to do this

- take the photo for the hand-written digit (like `4` in the example)
- use image tool to crop and resize to 8*8 as `4.png`
- inside the code above, convert to grey and save into array
- let original code to predict this new digit

Answer (score 0):

Another variant of what Larry does:

```
img = imageio.imread(pic_path)
 # dirty hack to tranform into the format, sklearn needs it
img = [16-int(round(jj/16)) for j in img for jj in j]

predicted = classifier.predict(img)


image = np.reshape(img, (8,8))
plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

print('Predicted: {0}'.format(predicted))
```